# javascript code is starting value on next line

Tags: javascript, html, css

Okay; so I managed to get my counter working (and it works well, I guess; not sure if it's efficient or whatever) but for some reason my code is outputting like this:

593.63

Logs,

593.63

Clay,

593.63

Metal

When it should be all on one line, why is it doing this? here is my current code:

```
var curAmntLogs = 448.34;
var curAmntClay = 448.34;
var curAmntMetal = 448.34;

var maxResources = 1000;

var curLogsPerSec = 1.67;
var curClayPerSec = 1.67;
var curMetalPerSec = 1.67;

function logs() {
    curAmntLogs = curAmntLogs + curLogsPerSec;
    if (curAmntLogs > maxResources) {
      curAmntLogs = maxResources;
    }
    document.getElementById('logs').innerHTML = (curAmntLogs).toFixed(2);
}

function clay() {
    curAmntClay = curAmntClay + curClayPerSec;
    if (curAmntClay > maxResources) {
      curAmntClay = maxResources;
    }
    document.getElementById('clay').innerHTML = (curAmntClay).toFixed(2);
}

function metal() {
    curAmntMetal = curAmntMetal + curMetalPerSec;
    if (curAmntMetal > maxResources) {
      curAmntMetal = maxResources;
    }
    document.getElementById('metal').innerHTML = (curAmntMetal).toFixed(2);
}


setInterval(function(){ logs(); clay(); metal(); }, 1000);
```

and I use this to display it on the webpage:

```
<div id='logs'></div> Logs, <div id='clay'></div> Clay, <div id='metal'></div> Metal
```

How do I make it all on one line? Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`div` tags will generally use a new block, the same way a new paragraph would. Try using span tags instead, or style your div tags with the css: `display:inline`.

Comment: Oh, silly me! I tried using styling as well, I didn't know div tags start a new block, thank you! I will select you as the correct answer when it lets me (gotta wait a few minutes)

Comment: Seriously, try it first. I'm not 100% sure about it myself, I'm just going from memory.

Comment: Yeah, I'd agree, Niet. However, sometimes there's a good reason for it being a `div` tag that's not obvious from the question, such as the html being generated by something the OP can't easily change.

Comment: Do you mean `display:inline`? Also setting the div to inline will mean any width/height settings are ignored, it would be better to use `inline-block`, `float:left` or `spans` like you mentioned (but spans aren't great if you needed to add margins). See this [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ZUB9J/2/).

Comment: Yeah, I did say I hadn't checked it :) I've corrected it now.